# Add clickable function in functions.php - parse error

Tags: errors

I'm trying to add onclick event to a div. But Wordpress keep saying that my function is undefined.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: thfull is not defined

> function thfull()  {
> echo "document.getElementById('thf').style.maxHeight = '1000px';";
> }
> add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thfull');

html:

> < div class="thumbnail" id="thf" onclick="thfull()">

The whole point is to toggle css class on div.

I'm a total noob when it comes to JS and stuff like that... Please help.

Comment: Hello Serpher - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately, you simply can't call a PHP function from JavaScript. One is executing per-request on the server and the other persistently in the visitor's web-browser - they can't talk to each other without HTTP requests or another network transport. The error you are receiving is from your browser's JS engine, not WordPress. As this is a question regarding PHP/JS language fundamentals rather than WordPress or it's APIs, this question may be considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Further, you should not be printing anything in a `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook. All of this said, you should adjust your code such that the only thing the PHP side is doing is enqueueing a dedicated file containing your JavaScript. In your JavaScript file, define the *JavaScript function* which you intend to attach to the HTML element.

Comment: you can't call PHP functions directly from javascript, they don't run on the same machine and they aren't the same programming language. Your PHP runs on a server in a data centre, your javascript runs in a browser on a machine in front of you, you can't mix them like that,

Answer (score 1):

For clarity's sake regarding my comments, this is something more akin to what I'm talking about...

```php
// plugins/wpse392844/wpse392844.php

function wpse392844_enqueue_assets() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'wpse392844-frontend',
    plugins_url( 'assets/js/frontend.js', __FILE__ )
  );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse392844_enqueue_assets' );
```

```js
// plugins/wpse392844/assets/js/frontend.js

function thfull() {
  document.getElementById('thf').style.maxHeight = '1000px';
}
```

(we're defining the `thfull()` function in JavaScript rather than PHP such that the browser will be aware of and able to use it. The PHP just makes sure that the browser loads the JS)

Comment: In the meantime I asked that question, I did it like this. Dunno if it is entirely correct but works.

`
function thfull() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'thumbnail_full', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/thumbnail_full.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thfull');
`

`
thf.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 thf.classList.toggle("thfull");
})